# Statistical significance in users research experiment

Tags: statistics, hypothesis-testing, confidence-interval, experimental-mathematics

If a company sends out 100 emails to a user. These emails are opened at different hours of the day. During some of the hours, the user is more likely to open the mail.

I want to understand how many emails out of 100 must be opened in a particular hour to be able to say that the user responds effectively in that particular hour?

When I try to find the confidence interval with : 
Population = 100
Sample size = 15 (average number of open a user has over 100 mails sent)
Confidence level = 95
Percentage = 50 (open/no open)

I get Confidence level(or margin of error) = 23.45 
How do I interpret this ?

Comment: How did you obtain this number $23.45$? What was the expression that you evaluated to get that number?

Comment: I used this tool 'Find Confidence Interval' available at https://www.surveysystem.com/sscalc.htm

Comment: I don't really understand what the numbers that you have written represent, from the point of view of a statistical test. So your population is the 100 emails, and "success" is if it was opened in a certain window. How many successes were there? 15 or 50?

Comment: Anyway, looking at the calculator, I understood that it aims to calculate the **confidence interval for a proportion**. This means that given a sample population and how many successes there are, it aims to calculate how many successes there would be in an infinite population. The "leg" of the confidence interval is calculated by
$$
L = z \cdot \sqrt{\frac{\hat{p} (1- \hat{p})}{n}}
$$
where $z=1.96$ if you want 95% confidence level; $\hat{p}$ is the number of successes divided by $n$; $n$ is the sample size. This $L$ is what the calculator gives, in percentages (so multiplied by 100).

Comment: Once you have this "leg" length, you can use it make an approximation for the "real" $p$, which would be the proportion of successes in an infinite population:
$$
p = \hat{p} \pm L
$$
(that's why I call it the "leg" - because it splits up like that :)

Comment: So what I am trying to find is this(the interpretation can be totally wrong though) : If I have sent 100 emails to a user how many of these must be opened by the user so that I can that it is not happening by chance?[ what is the statistically significant number] Also, I believe I need to go through some books to improve my understanding of these concepts. Can you suggest some book/link for beginner to advanced stats?

Comment: Seems like an odd question: When you open an email, what's the difference of it happening by chance, versus doing it deliberately? Why do you need to research this kind of question?

Comment: I have explained the problem statement here , I hope it is helpful : https://docs.google.com/document/d/1R4zVbixraNYiS1ua7FxTO7YkSo_87PoKGDZi-_0G2aM/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Ahaa, perhaps a different statistical test altogether is needed. Perhaps instead of a confidence interval for a proportion, you need to compare several sets of data! Perhaps you need to carry out something like an ANOVA test ...

Comment: Ah okay, I will check it out. Thanks a lot !!